# how to reset the azure pipeline service connection's password with new password generated with pwsh scripts

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have a bunch of service connections created in Azure pipeline to access the Unix/Linux VM though SSH tunnel, is it possible to change the password of the service connections with scripting, bash or pwsh?
The new password is generated with scripts and stored in azure key vault.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to change the password of the service connections with scripting, bash or pwsh? The new password is generated with scripts and stored in azure key vault.

Yes. You can achieve it by using Rest API：[Endpoints - Update Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/update-service-endpoint?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Here is the PWSH Example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url=" https://dev.azure.com/{Oranization}/{Project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{serviceconnectionid}?api-version=6.0-preview.4"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json

Write-Host "Currentconfiguration = $($response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$response.authorization.parameters.password= "$(keyvaultname)"


$json = @($response) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
```

To get the Azue Key Vault value, you can use the Azure CLI: [az keyvault secret show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_secret_show)

```
az keyvault secret show [--id]
                        [--name]
                        [--query-examples]
                        [--subscription]
                        [--vault-name]
                        [--version]
```

Then you can inject the obtained secret value into the pwsh variable and apply it to the Rest API sample.